# Jpa repository saveAndFlush returning timestamps as null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_org")
public class Organization {

  /**
   * id of the organization.
   */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @Column(name = "c_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16) DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), TRUE))")
  private UUID id;

  /**
   * legal name of the organization.
   */
  @Column(name = "c_legal_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String legalName;

  /**
   * alias name of the organization.
   */
  @Column(name = "c_alias", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String alias;

  /**
   * timestamp when the organization was created.
   */
  @Column(name = "c_date", insertable = false, updatable = false,
      columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
      nullable = false)
  private Instant ts;
}
```

now when I am saving this entity from service and when I want to access timestamp by calling saveAndFlush(orgObject).getTs();

Timestamp is always null but I can see it is getting saved in database but jpa not returning it.

I tried annotating it with @CreationTimestamp but that will set jvm's timestamp and I want db's timestamp.

Comment: First read the doc of `@Column(columnDefinition)` to be sure that the definition is used when the table is created, or, second if you want SQL timestamp, just set a default value to your `c_date` column : `CREATE TABLE t_org (..., c_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ... );`

Comment: AFAIK `saveAndFlush()` does not update (all) fields on a new entity, as it calls `persist()` under the hood. Only for updates this could work, as it calls `merge()` in those cases. [SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/2.7.3/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L661)

Comment: @Zorglube I already have defined c_date column with  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @DUMBLEDHOR: based on @XtremeBaumer you should try to refresh the entity. For that use the EntityManager. `Entity e = saveAndFlush(e); em.refresh(e); e.getTs();`

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and this is fetching the timestamp. I created an entity class called post. and made API controller and service class for that. Here is the whole code.

**Post entity class**

```
package com.project.demo.entity;

import java.time.Instant;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder 
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; 
    private String thePost; 
    private Instant creationTime; 
}
```

**service class**

```
package com.project.demo.service;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.project.demo.entity.Post;
import com.project.demo.repository.PostRepository;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
public class PostService {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository; 

    @Transactional
    public List<Post> getPosts(){
        return postRepository.findAll(); 
    }

    @Transactional
    public void savePost(Post post) {
        post.setCreationTime(Instant.now());
        postRepository.save(post);
    }
}
```

**controller class for rest API**

```
package com.project.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.project.demo.entity.Post;
import com.project.demo.service.PostService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/posts")
    public List<Post> getPost() {
        return postService.getPosts();
    }

    @PostMapping("/posts")
    public String savePost(@RequestBody Post post) {
        post.setId(0);
        postService.savePost(post);
        return "Post saved";
    }
}
```

**application.property**

```
spring.datasource.name=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stackoverflow
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**The screenshots of fetched data in postman**

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdAUK.png)

Hope this helps.